# libvirtd.service could not found

Tags: libvirt

when I try to start libvirt using `sudo systemctl start libvirtd` 
`Failed to start libvirtd.service: Unit libvirtd.service not found.` occured.

And when i try to apt list to detect is here libvirt

`apt list | grep libvirt` results is that

**gir1.2-libvirt-glib-1.0/focal 3.0.0-1 amd64 

gir1.2-libvirt-sandbox-1.0/focal 0.5.1+git20160404-1ubuntu2 amd64

libnss-libvirt/focal-updates 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.14 amd64

libvirt-clients/focal-updates,now 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.14 amd64 [installed]

libvirt-daemon-driver-lxc/focal-updates 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.14 amd64

libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu/focal-updates 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.14 amd64

libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-gluster/focal-updates 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.14 amd64

libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-rbd/focal-updates 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.14 amd64

libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-zfs/focal-updates 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.14 amd64

libvirt-daemon-driver-vbox/focal-updates 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.14 amd64

libvirt-daemon-driver-xen/focal-updates 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.14 amd64

libvirt-daemon-system-systemd/focal-updates 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.14 amd64

libvirt-daemon-system-sysv/focal-updates 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.14 amd64

libvirt-daemon-system/focal-updates 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.14 amd64

libvirt-daemon/focal-updates 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.14 amd64

libvirt-dbus/focal-updates,focal-security 1.3.0-1ubuntu1 amd64

libvirt-dev/focal-updates 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.14 amd64

libvirt-doc/focal-updates 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.14 all

libvirt-glib-1.0-0/focal 3.0.0-1 amd64

libvirt-glib-1.0-dev/focal 3.0.0-1 amd64

libvirt-ocaml-dev/focal 0.6.1.5-1build1 amd64

libvirt-ocaml/focal 0.6.1.5-1build1 amd64

libvirt-sandbox-1.0-5/focal 0.5.1+git20160404-1ubuntu2 amd64

libvirt-sandbox-1.0-dev/focal 0.5.1+git20160404-1ubuntu2 amd64

libvirt-sanlock/focal-updates 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.14 amd64

libvirt-wireshark/focal-updates 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.14 amd64

libvirt0/focal-updates,now 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.14 amd64 [installed,automatic]

libvirtodbc0/focal 6.1.6+repack-0ubuntu10 amd64

libvirtualpg-dev/focal 2.0.0~rc0-1 amd64

libvirtualpg0/focal 2.0.0~rc0-1 amd64

libvirtuoso5.5-cil/focal 6.1.6+repack-0ubuntu10 amd64

nbdkit-plugin-libvirt/focal 1.16.2-1ubuntu3 amd64

nova-compute-libvirt/focal-updates 2:21.2.2-0ubuntu1 all

php-libvirt-php/focal 0.5.5-1 amd64

python3-libvirt/focal 6.1.0-1 amd64

ruby-fog-libvirt/focal 0.6.0-1 all

ruby-libvirt/focal 0.7.1-1build1 amd64

uvtool-libvirt/focal 0~git169-0ubuntu1 all

vagrant-libvirt/focal 0.0.45-2 all**

I don't know what is the this problem and how to i fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer to [Ubuntu documents](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/virtualization-libvirt):

```
# To install the necessary packages, from a terminal prompt enter:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-system
```

You should check and follow some necessary steps or configures according to the document.